# How to recover key password with Android Studio 3.4 and with gradle 5.5

Tags: android, android-studio, sign

When I sign apk I got message "Cannot recover key"
I know alias name and keystore password, but I forgot the key password, I don't know any idea I use android studio 3.4 and gradle 5.5.
I tried with idea.log file but there password with ******* and I looked gradle history files but doesn't find.
Know I don't have any idea how to recover or find my key password...

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/keystore-password-recovery

Answer (score 2):

Open the project in Android Studio. On the left pane select Project option to display all the files and folders in your project. You'll find the .gradle folder, inside that you'll find the folder with your gradle number, mine was 5.1.1

Inside that folder, you'll find the executionHistory Folder, and inside that executionHistory.bin file. Open that file in Android Studio itself.

Now search(Ctrl+f) in that file for signingConfig.keyPassword and you'll find more than 1 matches. GO THROUGH ALL OF THEM and you'll find your password after one of these matches.

PS - I'm using Android Studio 3.5 [Folder Tree for my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKFyv.png)

Good Luck